# FlutterActivity completely overlaying the view

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, module

I'm trying to create a FlutterActivity that is capable of displaying a Flutter module but also displaying a native android BottomNavigation Bar. However, the Flutter module and UI is completely overlaying the Activity View, not showing the BottomNavigation Bar. Has anyone experienced this situation and can give a way to resolve it?

```
fun startFlutterModule(context: Context, action: String? = null) {

    val methodChannel = getMethodChannel(context)

    val cfid = recoverCfid()

    val map = mutableMapOf(
        "difc" to cfid,
        "application" to environmentSelected
    )
    if (action != null) {
        map["action"] = action
    }

    methodChannel.invokeMethod("showFlutterModule", map)

    context.startActivity(FlutterActivity
        .withCachedEngine("for_start_engine")
        .build(context))

    hasFlutterActivityRunning = true
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<activity
  android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>

**Dependecies**
debugImplementation 'com.valemobi.flut.integration_agora_flutter:flutter_debug:1.0'
profileImplementation 'com.valemobi.flut.integration_agora_flutter:flutter_profile:1.0'
releaseImplementation 'com.valemobi.flut.integration_agora_flutter:flutter_release:1.0'
```